# PHP Library for Authentication and Permissions/Access Control

Tags: php, authentication, openid, controls

Until now, I've been the only person who has had access to the editing tools/forms for my sites content, so using http authentication in an SSL protected directory has worked for me.

About to add someone to the content entering team so I'm wondering what PHP libraries you'd recommend for authentication and permission/access control to the form entry pages.

From looking around here, I see that OpenID is the highly recommended for the password aspect. I'm now wondering about the access control. Essentially our content entry forms are in a bunch of job specific files like:

newsentry.php
photocaption.php
nominations.php, etc. I'm looking for a system that enables me to say this form can be used by Person A, this one by A+B, etc.

Obviously I don't want to reinvent the wheel and want something that people have faith in as relatively bulletproof.

The site's run on a homespun CMS, so I'm assuming I'm looking for an Access Control System that can be run using a php include and some additional coding in each file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) and [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html)... You might also be interested in [Zend_Openid](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html)

Comment: integrating the zend frame  work will actualy take a loot of time

Comment: @streetparade:

Thats nonsense. It wouldnt take any longer than using another library, unless of course you are already familiar with the other one.

Comment: To clarify, you can use Zend_Auth and _Acl without having to have a "Zend Framework App", the components work really well standalone

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something a Role Based Access Control library instead of an ACL, you might want to check out [PHP-Bouncer](http://code.google.com/p/php-bouncer/) (Full Disclosure: I am the main coder behind PHP-Bouncer). I built PHP-Bouncer because Zend_Acl did not seem to provide the flexibility I needed.